# firewalld локальное перенаправление порта в service

Tags: linux, firewall

Возможно ли в **firewalld** используя **service** перенаправить локальный порт?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
    <short>Direct Connect server (PtokaX)</short>
    <description>Opens ports for P2P Direct Conect server PtokaX</description>
    <forward-port port="411" protocol="tcp" to-port="4111"/>
    <forward-port port="411" protocol="udp" to-port="4111"/>
</service>
```

В **zone** директива **forward-port** работает, но в **service** не работает.
Нужно это правило добавить в **rpm**-пакет, чтобы оно добавлялось и удалялось вместе с соответствующим демоном. Как быть? [man firewalld.service](http://www.firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.service.html)